# DateRngePicker in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

here I have a fragmented DatePicker working fine. But select 1 day at a time ... I would like to select several days

**My Fragment class**

```
public class student extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        edittext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showDatePicker();
                }
            });
    }

    private void showDatePicker() {
        DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
        /**
        * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
        */
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        date.setArguments(args);
        /**
        * Set Call back to capture selected date
        */
        date.setCallBack(ondate);
        date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }

    OnDateSetListener ondate = new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

            edittext.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear+1)
               + "-" + String.valueOf(year));
        }
    };            
}
```

other class **DatePickerFragment.java**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    OnDateSetListener ondateSet;
    private int year, month, day;

    public DatePickerFragment() {}

    public void setCallBack(OnDateSetListener ondate) {
        ondateSet = ondate;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
        super.setArguments(args);
        year = args.getInt("year");
        month = args.getInt("month");
        day = args.getInt("day");
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);
    }
}
```

tentei outro forama com ou design de material mais na função dentro do fragmet...
Please help me

I accept another suggestion but it has to be within a frament

Comment: Use the MaterialDatePicker included in the Material Components Library

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it, however, when I included it, depending on the material design, it returns this error to me. At the moment, I am trying to migrate to Androidx, so I am afraid that it is being very busy ** This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled ** is there no way to do this automatically?